# Getting error when redirecting on select change using React Router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm creating a React app in which I use React Router v4. I have built a dropdown menu and I want users to be redirected to a different page when they select their prefered option. The redirect does work, but when the new route is rendered the select disappears and the following error pops up:

```
Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/you/your-favorite-news"
```

Here's the component that renders and handles the select:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class Select extends React.Component {

    constructor( props ) {

        super( props );

        this.state = {
            value: this.props.currentUrl, 
            redirect: false, 
        } 

        this.handleSelectChange = this.handleSelectChange.bind( this ); 

    }

    handleSelectChange( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            value: event.target.value,
            redirect: true
        });     
    }

    renderSelectOptions() { 
        return this.props.selectOptions.map( option => {
            return <option key={ option.id } value={ option.slug }>{ option.title }</option>
        }); 
    }

    render() {

        const redirect = this.state.redirect; 

        if( redirect ) {
            return <Redirect to={ "/you/" + this.state.value } />; 
        }       

        return (
            <select 
                name="user-nav-select" 
                id="user-nav-select" 
                value={ this.state.value }
                onChange={ this.handleSelectChange }>{ this.renderSelectOptions() }</select>
        );

    }

}

export default Select;
```

I should mention that the app I'm creating is rendered on the server on initial page load, so I'm actually using the `react-router-config` package and declaring my routes as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

import App from "./App";
import ArchivePage from "./pages/ArchivePage";
import HomePage from "./pages/HomePage";
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage";
import SinglePostPage from "./pages/SinglePostPage";
import UserPage from "./pages/UserPage";

export default [
    {
        ...App, 
        routes: [
            {
                ...HomePage, 
                path: '/', 
                exact: true
            },
            {
                ...ArchivePage, 
                path: '/tag/:slug'
            },  
            {
                ...UserPage, 
                path: '/you/:slug'
            },      
            {
                ...LoginPage, 
                path: '/login'
            },              
            {
                ...SinglePostPage, 
                path: '/:slug'
            },                                                  
        ]
    }
];
```

What could be causing that error?

Comment: try using <Switch> when your're rendering routes.

Comment: your constructor is not called every time the component rerenders, the render function does. So `this.state.redirect` is not set back to `false` after the component rendered. Use `componentDidUpdate` for example

Comment: @Tikkes Thank you for chipping in! I did just try what you suggested, which cleared the original error but I'm getting a new one now: `Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate.`

Comment: Yes, this is because you are, in `componentDidUpdate`, resetting the state. Which, in turn, reactivates the same method.

Comment: So is there a more appropriate method that I can use to reset the state? I'm sorry but I'm not too familiar with a component's lifecycle!